# Including source of file inside a Vue-cli project (type jscad)

Tags: vue.js, axios, openjscad

### I want to load a .jscad file into a vue component.

I have set up an vue-cli project, installed this [openjscad-vue viewer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@jwc/vue-openjscad) using npm and am using the openjscad component. This component has the prop *design* which should allow specifying a path to a .jscad file for the openjscad viewer. This is not working properly.

**Tried to find the error and do a workaround:**
Inside this component (*OpenJscad.Vue*) is a `fetch()` request to load the .jscad file, but it doesnt work. To be sure that the openjscad processors is working correctly I used a plain string containing the .jscad code as source and this works!
But I want a whole .jscad file loaded.

I think the fetch request is the problem. I only need a static .jscad file to be loaded from the same server the vue-cli project is serving.

I've tried this:

- using axios:

```
async mounted() {
[...]
await axios.get("/logo.jscad").then(response => (this.source = response));
```

- installed *raw-loader/file-loader* and configure it inside vue.config.js. Imported the file from the assets folder. -> Webpack loader error. It seems to me that vue.config.js is ignored?

```
import logo from "logo.jscad"
this.source = logo
```

Any recommendation to solve this problem?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To answer part of my own question and maybe help other people:

the vue.config.js file do **not** have to be at same directory as package.json. It is only loaded and used after put inside the */src* directory next to *main.js* or *App.vue*